# regex rejects part of the first group (order)

Tags: regex, validation, match, email-validation, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to modify an existing email regex to allow one hyphen between characters, exactly as the dot delimiter.

```
^([\w]+(?:\.[\w]+)*(?:\-[\w]+)*){1,64}@((?:[\w]+\.)*\w[\w]{0,64})\.([a-z]{2,7})$
```

I'm having problems with the order: if I use the hyphen first and then the dot, the regex ignores everything at the left of the character before dot:

`my-cool.email@domain.com` -> <s>`my-coo`</s>`l.email@domain.com` (don't mind the blank space).

The max length limit for the first two groups is 64, but it's not working, when I put more than 64 characters it passes the regex, and it's valid. The third group max length is 7, and it won't validate if it's more.

you can take as an example: `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.aa` is a good result

and

`aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.aa` is a bad result.

The first example have 64 `a`s before and after the `@` and the second example have 65 `a`s

https://regex101.com/r/yO1xH7/3

I'd also like to do the same after the `@`, but it's more complicated than I thought.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a little mistake where you put the hyphen. This is the right one:

```
^([\w]+(?:[\.\-][\w]+)*(?:[\w]+)*){1,64}@((?:[\w]+\.)*\w[\w]{0,64})\.([a-z]{2,7})$
```

I guess you don't understand because you don't know the function of `?:`. It's Regex non capturing group. It's meant to avoid that pattern there.

Comment: Define the length limit you want, then I can help you

Comment: I mean define it with word. Maybe give me an example of too long email that pass the regex and what it should be

Comment: I've seen your regex multiple times. I need to explain in **human** language, not code language. Give me expected result, and what is the current wrong result. Update your question post and tell me when it is done.

Comment: It's still hard to understand without any sample of bad and good result

Comment: Maybe is a bug in the regex101.com page. Or maybe is a problem with the regex, I'm getting Catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109491/discussion-between-aminah-nuraini-and-chazy-chaz).